# Delete a file which I only know the first part of the name in PHP

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I want to delete a file which I only know the first part of the name.

```
    unlink('./upload/nav_thumbs/project-'  .the rest);
```

'the rest' = can be anything. Only thing I got is that is has a .jpg extension

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$possibleFiles = glob('./upload/nav_thumbs/project-*.jpg');
foreach ($possibleFiles as $file) {
    if (thisIsTheFileYouAreLookingFor($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

http://php.net/glob

Comment: +1 nice!!! I didn't know the `glob()` trick - learning new things here everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the OOP version too:

```
 $directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator('./upload/nav_thumbs');
 foreach($directoryIterator as $fileInfo)
     if(i_want_to_delete($fileInfo->getFilename()) unlink($fileInfo->getFilename());
```